# Adding labels while converting SVC FaceClassification model to CoreML using, converters.sklearn.convert

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, coreml, coremltools, facenet

I have trained a model to classify faces based on FaceNet, and while I am trying to convert the model to CoreML model using [`converters.sklearn.convert`](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/docs-api-version3/generated/coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert.html), I do not get class labels embedded to it by default, how can I add class labels to my CoreML model.

This my current script that converts the model

```
classFeatureNames = ("Prediction","Probability")
coreml_model = ct.converters.sklearn.convert(model,input_features='inputArray', output_feature_names=classNames)
coreml_model.save("celebritySix.mlmodel")
```

Model generated using above script returns me labels as, [0,1,2,3,4,5] while I am expecting the respective name of person detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [coremltools convert docs](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/docs-api-version3/generated/coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert.html):

> "If it is a classifier, output_feature_names should be a 2-tuple of names giving the top class prediction and the array of scores for each class (defaults to “classLabel” and “classScores”)."

Most `scikit-learn` estimators have a `classes_` attribute where labels are stored. Either the model was not trained with the right class labels, or coremltools is not correctly applying the attribute when converting.

**MRE** with `Y` / `N` labels:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import coremltools

X, y = make_classification(n_clusters_per_class=1, n_informative=4, n_classes=2)
y_new = np.zeros_like(y, dtype=np.str_)
y_new[y == 0] = "N"
y_new[y == 1] = "Y"

clf = SVC().fit(X, y_new)
# clf.classes_
# ['N' 'Y']

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(clf)
coreml_model.save("demo_output.mlmodel")
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander L. Hayes , with your solution I reviewed my fit() operation where I had used LabelEncoder() encoded labels as one of parameter. Replacing it with classNames resolved the issue.